# My search button not displaying data

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Am building window form application for a clinic using VS2010. 
On the form in have a searchbutton that display data baseon the RegistrationNo.
When i test the application, provide the Registration number and click the search
button nothing is display, and no error message is display too.
Here is my code

```
        string connectionstring = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=HMS;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Developer;Password=abc@123";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

        string SelectStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable where RegistrationNo = '@RegistraionNo'";
        SqlCommand insertcommand = new SqlCommand(SelectStatement, connection);
        insertcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistrationNo", txtsearch.Text);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            reader = insertcommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                textBox3.Text = reader["RegistratioNo"].ToString();
                textBox1.Text = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                genderOption.Text = reader["Sex"].ToString();
                textBox7.Text = reader["Contact"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = reader["Age"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = reader["Weight"].ToString();
                textBox6.Text = reader["Weight"].ToString();
                comboBox1.Text = reader["Tribe"].ToString();

            }//end while
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }//end catch
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }// end finally
```

`

Comment: You're probably not getting an error because you're only catching SqlExceptions, any other type of exception will not be seen. Change your catch clause to catch (Exception ex), and you should be able to see the error.

Comment: You shouldn't `throw ex`, unless you like burying your `Exceptions` within `InnerExceptions`.

Comment: Thanks that was good observation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo

RegistraionNo instead of RegistrationNo

in

```
string SelectStatement = "SELECT * FROM MyTable where RegistrationNo = '@RegistraionNo'";
```

another in

```
textBox3.Text = reader["RegistratioNo"].ToString();
```

You'll copy 100 lines of

> I want a registration, I want a registration, I want a registration.

Comment: Thank you body:Raphael Althaus